# Segmented controls with 2 buttons

Tags: iphone, sdk, uibutton, background-image, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to create a segmented control with 2 Round rect buttons but don't know how to set the 'forState' for Highlighted button.

Others said to set the background image in IB and modify the Image programmatically

Tried:

```
[buttonName setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UnselectedImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonName setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SelectedImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

The problem is the background image doesn't remanins after I've clicked on it, any clue?

Comment: Thank you guys for your tips & tricks; an easier way to do it is using segmented controls (an Switch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following code:

1 Image:

```
int iButtonState = 1;

if (iButtonState  == 1) {
    [buttonName setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    iButtonState = 2;
} else if (iButtonState  == 2) {
    [buttonName setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Other.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    iButtonState = 1;
}
```

2 Images:

```
int iButtonState = 1;
int iTabImageA = 1;
int iTabImageB = 1;

if (iButtonState  == 1) {
    if (iTabImageA == 1) {
        [buttonName setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageA1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        iTabImageA = 2;
    } else if (iTabImageA == 2) {
        [buttonName setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageA2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        iTabImageA = 1;
    }
    iButtonState = 2;
} else if (iButtonState  == 2) {
    if (iTabImageB == 1) {
        [buttonName setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageB1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        iTabImageB = 2;
    } else if (iTabImageB == 2) {
        [buttonName setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageB2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        iTabImageB = 1;
    }
    iButtonState = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "highlighted" state is used only while the user touches the button. As soon as the user release his/her finger from the button, the states goes back to normal.

You may try using the "Selected" state instead (not tested but worth trying as it seems quite logical). If it doesn't work, you may need to change the "selected" state of your buttons yourself by code (in the button action or the segmentedControl delegate methods)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the selected image for `UIControlStateSelected`, rather than `UIControlStateHighlighted`

Answer (score 1):

A UIButton is kind of like a momentary switch. It doesn't have a "hot now" state. "Highlighted" is literally just while it's being tapped, and then it's out of that state.

It seems like you maybe need some external variable to track the state of your buttons, and maybe to manage the twiddling of the images, too.

I like that image. That's going to be a nice effect, once you get it running.

Comment: Any idea how to add some text above them?